# Matching a set of answers to two tables in MySQL with a list of best matches with score in percentage

Tags: mysql

I have the following 2 tables:

**Table Club**

```
Club_ID | Position 1 | Position 2  | Position 3

Club-A  |    Y       |    N        |    Y

Club-B  |    N       |    Y        |    Y

Club-C  |    N       |    Y        |    Y
```

---

**Table Member**

```
Club_Member |   Club_ID

Person A    |   Club-A

Person B    |   Club-B

Person C    |   Club-A

Person D    |   Club-B

Person E    |   Club-C
```

---

I have a set of questions to which a set of answers is given by the user:

Answer to Position 1: $A1

Answer to Position 2: $A2

Answer to Position 3: $A3

---

How can I make a query to my MYSQL database such that I can provide the following list of (max 4) answers?

The 4 club members that best fits your views are:

1. Person C (Club-C) (100% match)
2. Person B (Club-B) (100% match)
3. Person C (Club-B) (100% match)
4. Person A (Club-A) (33% match)

Comment: I can't figure out what you're asking. I don't think there's enough information, where are you storing the questions and answers?

Comment: No? My two tables are stored in my database. The user fills in a questionnaire on a webpage, which will send the answers as variables. So I have to match the answers against the info in the tables. Once matched, i want to display the list of club members that match the answers provided by the user.